# Setting up nginx, rewrite and fastcgi

Tags: nginx, rewrite, fastcgi

This problem has been driving me nuts for the last couple of days... Working on an application that needs authentication and exists of different parts (CMS, API, frontend) we ran in to some problems with sharing sessions/cookies/cross-origin requests. In the end I thought it was easiest just to implement everything under one domain;

- scheme://app/ for the frontend
- scheme://app/api for the API
- scheme://app/cms for the CMS

this caused some troubles for the API build in php. The API expects request_uri's like /users /images instead of /api/users and /api/users. We thought a simple rewrite would be the solution, but somehow the request_uri doesn't get rewritten.

Here's the server setup:

```
server {
    listen 9090;
    server_name coda.dev;

    access_log      /usr/local/var/log/nginx/coda.access.log;
    error_log       /usr/local/var/log/nginx/coda.debug.log notice;
    charset         utf-8;

    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:9000;
    }

    location /api {
        root /Volumes/HDD/Sites/opdrachten/CODAapi/laravel/public;
        try_files $uri /index.php;
    }

    location ~/cms {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:9000;
    }

    location ~ \.php {            
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9091;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include       /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /Volumes/HDD/Sites/opdrachten/CODAapi/laravel/public;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /Volumes/HDD/Sites/opdrachten/CODAapi/laravel/public/index.php;
        break;
    }
}
```

I also tried adding this to overwrite the request_uri:

```
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri?$args;
```

But this resulted in every request getting the request_uri index.php

So how can I send all the requests starting with /api to the directory of my API and rewrite the request_uri to remove /api from the uri?